# Even after adding annotations in JUnit it says no test cases with testrunner.How to handle?

Tags: selenium, junit4

I have downloaded all the JUnit jar files and installed them.When I run my package as JUnit,it says no tests found with TestRunner 'JUnit 4'.What am I missing

```
*public class AmazonTestFactory{

static WebDriver driver;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    driver= new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.amazon.co.uk");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

}

@Test
public void testHomePage(){
    AmazonHomePageFactory Page = PageFactory.initElements(driver, PageFactoryModelExercise.AmazonHomePageFactory.class);
    Page.enterProductInSearchBox();
    Page.clickSearchButton();
}

@After
public void closeBrowser(){
    driver.close();
}*
```

Comment: Can you add a code sniped of a test with the annotations to your post.

Comment: added.Please help

Comment: I was able to sort it.I had imported a wrong JUnit Test.import org.junit.Test; worked.Thanks a lot